# How to show dialog box without needing a metro accent theme?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dialog, mahapps.metro

I want to show a metro-style dialog box like so:

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);
   await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Title", "Body");
}
```

[image]

However, it kept throwing the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

With the stack trace:

> at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog.HandleTheme()
>
> at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog.Initialize()
>
> at MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs.BaseMetroDialog..ctor(MetroWindow owningWindow, MetroDialogSettings settings)
>
> ...
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

So after a lot of fiddling, I realized I needed to include an accent in my `App.xaml` resources to give it a color scheme.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Cobalt.xaml" />
```

However, I've built my program without that and including it has messed with all my styling. Furthermore, there aren't many accents total [see here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Accents) and I can't find one that fits with my scheme.

I've been trying to give the `ShowMessageAsync` method it's own color scheme directly with commands such as

```
metroWindow.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme 
// MetroDialogColorScheme.Theme 
// MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented 
// MetroDialogColorScheme.Inverted;
```

But the same error continues to appear. Is there some way to get around this? How could I get the dialog box to use my own style?

**Edit**

I've actually downloaded the file here: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Accents/Cobalt.xaml

And in `ResourceDirectory.MergedDictionaries` replaced

```
  <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Cobalt.xaml" />
```

With

```
  <ResourceDictionary Source="Cobalt.xaml" />
```

And that's enough to break the function. I can see that that theme is still in effect, but when I try to trigger the dialog box, the window will fade but the dialog box doesn't appear and I need to restart the program. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the `ThemeManager`. Set the `AppStyle` when your application start like so :

```
ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(this, ThemeManager.Accents.First(x => x.Name == "Red"), ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle().Item1);
```

Here is an example of theme avaible :

[image]

To use your own style you can add an accents like so :

```
ThemeManager.AddAccent("XpertdocBlue", new Uri("XpertdocBlue.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Try to add a `ResourceDictionary`

Here is mine:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Xpertdoc.PortalWordAddIn.Views;component/Resources/Icons.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="XpertdocBlue.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
```

And here is my Custom Accent (`XpertdocBlue.xaml`):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="HighlightColor">#FF2B579A</Color>

    <Color x:Key="AccentColor">#FF2B579A</Color>
    <!--60%-->
    <Color x:Key="AccentColor2">#CC2B579A</Color>
    <!--40%-->
    <Color x:Key="AccentColor3">#992B579A</Color>
    <!--20%-->
    <Color x:Key="AccentColor4">#662B579A</Color>

    <!-- re-set brushes too -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush2" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor2}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush3" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor3}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush4" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor4}"/>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowTitleColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentSelectedColorBrush" Color="White" />

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBrush" EndPoint="0.001,0.5" StartPoint="1.002,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AccentColor3}" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckmarkFill" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RightArrowFill" Color="{StaticResource AccentColor}" />

    <Color x:Key="IdealForegroundColor">White</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="IdealForegroundColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource IdealForegroundColor}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is putting me on the right track. How can I add a custom theme though? Because `ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle()` and `ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current)` returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks Cedric. Another trick I used to help me with the themes was specifying the theme of individual controls instead of the window. For instance, I wanted my datagrid styled using a different theme than the rest of the window. So I used the code   `<DataGrid.Resources> <ResourceDictionary Source="pack:/.../Accents/BaseLight.xaml" /> </DataGrid.Resources>`

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageDialog md=new MessageDialog("my message");
await md.showAsync();
```

If you want to create a custom messge dialog then you would have to create your own custom control. You could easily add styles to your custom dialog whenever required.